# Writing WP7 app which has facebook share or tweet using inbuilt application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to add a facebook share and twitter tweet options in my WP7 app. Like in Android I want a pop up to be opened showing list of in build apps that allow you to do. Because we have intents in Android. Are there are ways to send such notifications to OS in WP7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ShareStatusTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [`ShareLinkTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) will do this for you

Comment: Thanks dude. But how to do tagging for twitter and not for other social networks.

Comment: With those launchers, you get what comes out of the box with no scope for customisation.  If you need more than they give you, you will need to roll your own.